# I created a compare function for std::sort using lambda in C++, but I got an error

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

The compiler is gcc 11.1.0.I wrote this code.
https://wandbox.org/permlink/wYcz6Oalo9UyeLqd

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream> 
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n=5;
    vector<int>v(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        v[i]=i;
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](int i,int j){
        return [i,j](){
            if(i==j){return true;}
            else{return i>j;}};});
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<endl;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is here.It is long and has been abbreviated, and the full text is here.
https://wandbox.org/permlink/wYcz6Oalo9UyeLqd
I thought the if statement in the lambda unified the return value with bool and there was no problem, but there seems to be some problem. I could not figure it out.

```
In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /opt/wandbox/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/algorithm:61,
                 from prog.cc:1:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) [with _Iterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Iterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(int, int)>]':
/opt/wandbox/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1826:14:
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Looks like you've accidentally declared a lambda inside the lambda, so the outer lambda returns the inner lambda  rather than `bool`.

Comment: What code could be used to eliminate the double lambda and make the bool the return value?

Comment: `[](int i,int j){ if(i==j){return true;} else{return i>j;}}`. But once you have that fixed, you need to watch out. A sorting compare function is invalid if the compare function can return A < B = true and B< A = true, and that is precisely what the A==B test allows. See [Strict Weak Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) for  details. What you want is a function that returns whether or not A goes before B, and if A == B,  A before B is false.

Comment: if the purpose of this was to sort the vector descending, any reason why you don't just use `std::greater<int>()` as the third argument to `sort` and call it good (and as a bonus, fix your non-compliant comparator by excision in the process) ?

Comment: @user4581301 I learned a lot about lambda syntax and sorting notes. It was very useful.

Comment: @WhozCraig I wanted to understand how to use lambda.

Comment: Ah.. ok. sure. yeah, then `[](int a, int b){ return a > b; }` is probably what you will ultimately want. (which not coincidentally is what `std::greater<int>()` basically does, more or less).

Comment: I also wanted to use if statements. But thanks for commenting.